# PyODBC query with multiple wildcard parameters

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to use the following SQL query through `pyodbc`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE variable1 LIKE '%test1%' and variable2 LIKE '%test2%'
```

I found a way to do it for a single parameters on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984895/pyodbc-query-with-wildcards)

```
filter = 'test1'
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE variable1 LIKE ?"
param = f'%{filter}%'
rows = cursor.execute(sql, param).fetchall()
```

Can you please help me to write the `SQL` query on `pyodbc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go with the same approach of your example, just with 2 parameters:

```
filter1 = 'test1'
filter2 = 'test2'
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE variable1 LIKE ? AND variable2 LIKE ?"
params = (f'%{filter1}%',f'%{filter2}%') 
rows = cursor.execute(sql, params).fetchall()
```

Or simplify it a bit:

```
filter1 = 'test1'
filter2 = 'test2'
sql = f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE variable1 LIKE %{filter1}%? AND variable2 LIKE %{filter2}%?"
rows = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://ckhang.com/blog/2019/pyodbc-named-parameter-binding/)? It's related to named parameters binding and should support any arbitrary number or params.

Comment: No it wouldn't work because you need to pass multiple column names and parameters